# SAML Request - Declare Multiple Protocol Bindings

Tags: binding, protocols, saml

I have implemented a SAML Service Provider to support Single Sign On for an ASP.Net web portal, which is a shrink-wrap software configured on clients' sites and must be able to interact with any SAML-compliant Identity Provider.

My Assertion Consumer Service (ACS) page will accept the SAML Response through both GET and POST methods.

As I understand the SAML protocol, the SAML Request ***ProtocolBinding*** property specifies which protocols are supported for the response. Currently, my request specifies the HTTP-Redirect binding. However, I would like to declare that I support both *HTTP-Redirect* (GET) and *HTTP-POST* (POST). After searching through more SAML documentation than I care to reiterate, I am unable to find the syntax for declaring multiple supported protocol bindings (or whether it is even valid to do so).

While I could make this declaration configurable, my preference would be to declare both bindings so that the Identity Provider will work without additional configuration of my portal.

Below is a sample of my Authentication Request. Please, if anyone knows a way to declare both HTTP-Redirect AND HTTP-POST for the ProtocolBinding, I would greatly appreciate your input!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<samlp:AuthnRequest 
    xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
    ID="[AUTHN_ID]" 
    Version="2.0"
    IssueInstant="[ISSUE_INSTANT]"
    ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names.tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"
    ProviderName="[PROVIDER_NAME]"
    AssertionConsumerServiceURL="[ACS_URL]">
    <saml:Issuer xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
        PortalEntityID
    </saml:Issuer>
    <samlp:NameIDPolicy 
        AllowCreate="true" 
        Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified" />
</samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help!

Comment: My guess is that you ended up using a different value, so this wouldn't matter, but it looks like there was a small typo in the middle of the ProtocolBinding in the example given (`names.tc` vs `names:tc`).

Answer (score 6):

The ProtocolBinding attribute on AuthnRequest is used to specify the expected binding to be used by the IdP when sending their SAML Response XML.  HTTP-Redirect isn't a valid option to use here, because of the possible length restriction on the URL querystring; a SAML Response, especially if it's signed, can be pretty lengthy.  I'll quote from the SAML spec [SAMLProf]:

> ...the identity provider issues a <Response> message to be delivered by the user agent to the service provider.  Either the HTTP POST or HTTP Artifact binding can be used to transfer the message to the service provider through the user agent.  The message may indicate an error or will include (at least) an authentication assertion.  The HTTP Redirect binding MUST NOT be used, as the response will typically exceed the URL length permitted by most user agents.

Answer (score 0):

After considerable research, it seems that you can only declare one Protocol Binding in a single SAML request.